# Hyperref conflicts with footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, bugs

I dont know if this is a well known problem.

I recently used hyperref to make my table of contents clickable, but then I found out that throughout the document, wherever footnote would appear i.e.

[image]

Clicking on the footnote number will cause the pdf to jump back to the table of contents (which is on the first page).

Is there a way to prevent this behavior, or even better, clicking on the number makes the pdf jumps to the footnote?

---

Minimum Working Example as requested:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Preamble

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}       
\usepackage{amsmath}              
\usepackage{amsfonts}              
\usepackage{amsthm}                
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}                 % natha daga thia!
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\title{Ayuda Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\newpage
{\bfseries Things I love about Mexico}

\begin{longtable}{ | m{5.5cm} |}
Princess Yagoda\footnote{Tacos!}\\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\section{Uno}
\section{Dos}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem you're encountering. Be sure to mention which document class and which TeX or LaTeX format you employ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a problem of loading order of packages.  Generally `hyperref` needs to be the last package you load.  (There are some exceptions, see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/15925).)  Moving `hyperref` to be the last package loaded in your preamble fixes the linking problem of the footnote.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Preamble

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Ayuda Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\newpage
{\bfseries Things I love about Mexico}

\begin{longtable}{ | m{5.5cm} |}
Princess Yagoda\footnote{Tacos!}\\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\section{Uno}
\section{Dos}


\end{document}
```

The information about where to load the `hyperref` package may be found at the beginning of section 2 of the [`hyperref` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en), which you may be able to access via `texdoc hyperref` on your system.

Comment: Sincere thanks from Her highness Princess Yagoda!